How to dynamically add CDN that user wants to my React Project and use it in a client side editor
so here is the thing
I have a code editor in my React app ( Monaco - editor )
now I want to load the CDN that the user gives me ( think about it like the user enters his desired CDN in an input ) and load it in my Project and let him work with it in the code editor.
I think I could handle adding the CDN using pure JS but I can't figure out how to use that in the code Editor.
all other questions in the community was working with CDN by Developer but I want gives the CDN to the user.
